# Fortran - I do not understand variable declarations

Tags: arrays, fortran

I need to analize some Fortran code

```
         subroutine ilocz (a,b,c,n,m)
         real a(n,n),b(n,m),c(n,m)
         do 1 i=1,n
         do 2 j=1,m
         c(i,j)=0
         do 3 k=1,n
   3     c(i,j)=c(i,j)+a(i,k)*b(k,j)
   2     continue
   1     continue
         return
         end
```

In other place I'm calling this method

```
call ilocz (a(n11),y(2),a(n12),n,1)
```

I should refer to ilocz 5 variables - a, b, c, n, m . 
It is OK. But in first line in ilocz is declaration of arrays. They have te same name as my method arguments.

When i call ilocz i refer 5 real numbers (not arrays) to method.
How it is possible? How it works?

Maybe this number is assigned to every array element ( a(11) to a(n,n) , y(2) to b(n,m) , a(n12) to c(n,m) ) or something?

Could someone explain this to me ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17891508/3157076, http://stackoverflow.com/q/25000321/3157076.

Comment: So if I'll call ilocz:
a(1,1) = a(n12), 
a(1,2) = a(n12 + 1), 
....
a(1,n) = a(n12 + n - 1), 
a(2,1) = a (n12 + n), 
etc.
I understand this correctly ?

Comment: is `n=1` in this case?

Comment: no, in this case n = 4

Comment: I think I understand this. I will write it in C# to compare results and test myself. I'll ask you if you have problems.
thak You for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the same code, just modernized. As you can see it expects an array of reals for `a`,`b`, and `c`, but `FORTRAN` is great in that you can treat scalars like arrays

```
pure subroutine ilocz (a,b,c,n,m)
implicit none
! Arguments
integer, intent(in) :: n,m
real, intent(in)    :: a(n,n),b(n,m)
real, intent(out)   :: c(n,m)
! Local Vars
integer :: i,j,k
do i=1,n
    do j=1,m
    c(i,j)=0
        do k=1,n
          c(i,j)=c(i,j)+a(i,k)*b(k,j)
        end do
    end do
end do
return
end
```

This we can call as

```
call ilocz(a(1,1),b,a(2,1),1,1)
```

which takes the first element of `a`, the first element of `b` and writes into the 2nd element of `a`.

**Edit**

You can also use the following code:

```
do i=1,n
    do j=1,m
      c(i,j)=DOT_PRODUCT(a(i,1:n),b(1:n,i)
    end do
end do
```

or even

```
c = MATMUL(a,b)
```

<sup>see [Fortran matrix multiplication performance in different optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15580572/380384) for performance comparisons the different ways to do this</sup>